# Using atom package

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, atom-editor

I've installed two packages in my atom(jquery and bootstrap). I'm trying to figure out how to use those packages in my html code. For example im trying to create a bootstrap button. I write the code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

this only results in a regular button appearing on the page. Do i have to import the package or add something in the head of my code?

Comment: Have you linked all the css and js files with `<link>` and `<script>`?

Comment: No so since i installed the bootstrap package, where would i point the link to?

Comment: Usually you point it to a file but since i'm using a package how can i link them?

Comment: What do you mean you installed the bootstrap package?

Comment: In atom ide you go to packages, search and then install bootstrap. But after that it doesn't give you much instructions on how use or the installed package.

Comment: If it installs a bootstrap *editor* as in it install it for the IDE, then you have to link a cdn or local file.

Comment: Sorry not fully understanding this, if you still have to link it to a local file, what is the point of installing the package. Why not just link everything to a local file.

Comment: Bootstrap package just adds support for classes, etc. It doesn't actually link it AFAIK